# Aplicar o tema premium paradise do primefaces a um projeto que não é maven é possível?

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces

Consegui importar o war que vem no arquivo do tema e acessar os conteúdos, porém já tenho um projeto não maven começado e estrutura Spring Security montada funcionando corretamento já ..
Teria alguma maneira de implementar em meu projeto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, Adicionei minhas bibliotecas manualmente na pasta lib do projeto gerado pelo primefaces(war) e montei meu projeto por lá.